# Installing Qt headers and libraries

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, package-management, compile, qt

I am trying to compile and install some software. When I do the `./configure`. I get the following error:

> checking for Qt... configure: error: Qt (>= Qt 3.0.2) (headers and libraries) 
>     not found. Please check your installation!

So I install the following package thinking this would solve the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

I was thinking that the libqt4-dev would install the headers and libraries. However, I am still getting the same problem.

Any ideas?

Ubuntu 9.10
kernel 2.6.31-20-generic

---

**Edit:**  I am trying to install ***kgraphspace-0.3.0-pre1***.  I have installed KDE with *"sudo apt-get install kde-devel"*.  My KDE 3 includes are in */usr/include/KDE*, and shared libraries in */usr/lib/kde4*.

I am trying to run this command:

```
./configure --with-qt-includes=/usr/include/qt3/ --with-qt-libraries=/usr/lib/
              --prefix=/usr/lib/kde4
```

...and I get the following error:

```
checking for KDE... configure: error:
in the prefix, you've chosen, are no KDE libraries installed. This will fail.
So, check this please and use another prefix!
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are two problems with your existing `./configure` command:

1. `--with-qt-libraries=` should point to ***/usr/lib/qt3*** instead of ***/usr/lib/***, unless you've installed Qt3 libraries by hand and know they're at that location.
2. `--prefix=` needs to point to the base location where the package **will be installed**.  It doesn't point to anything needed for compiling the package.  ***/usr/lib/kde4*** is probably a bad choice; you'll need to add it to the $PATH to execute the program.  Most likely, you want `--prefix=/usr/local` or `--prefix=$HOME`, to install either to ***/usr/local/bin*** or ***/home/[username]/bin***, or stick with the program's default setting (***/usr/local/kde***).

---

On a fairly clean Ubuntu 9.10 virtual machine, I needed to install these packages and their dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install libqt3-headers libqt3-compat-headers libqt3-mt-dev
                  qt3-dev-tools qt3-dev-tools-compat kdelibs4-dev
```

---

Additionally, the `./configure` checks for several tools that were part of *aRts* -- the *mcopidl* and *artsc-config* commands, which are no longer included in any KDE packages in the standard Ubuntu repositories.  *aRts* was an old KDE sound library, and I believe it's been completely replaced or subsumed.

I've no idea if ***kgraphspace*** requires the sound functionality, so I created the shellscripts *$HOME/bin/mcopidl* and *$HOME/bin/artsc-config* that only contain this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hiya"
```

That's enough to satisfy the `./configure` checks, but won't work properly if these programs are actually called during compilation.

According to Ubuntu's repository websearch, the real programs were last available in Ubuntu 8.10 (Intrepid).  If you really need ***kgraphspace***, consider installing Ubuntu 8.04. (Hardy was the LTS release of that era, and its repositories will be around longer than the Intrepid repositories.)

---

Here's my working `./configure` command (options split into separate lines for clarity):

```
./configure --with-qt-includes=/usr/include/qt3 
            --with-qt-libraries=/usr/lib/qt3
            --prefix=/usr/local
```

---

Unfortunately, `make` dies with the following error, and this is as far as I can get in attempting to compile this software:

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/quack/test/kgraphspace-0.3.0-pre1/kgraphspace'
source='ktypesstats.cpp' object='ktypesstats.o' libtool=no \
        depfile='.deps/ktypesstats.Po' tmpdepfile='.deps/ktypesstats.TPo' \
        depmode=gcc3 /bin/bash ../admin/depcomp \
        g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I/usr/include/kde -I/usr/include/qt3
           -I. -Wall  -Wall  -c -o ktypesstats.o `test -f 'ktypesstats.cpp' ||
           echo './'`ktypesstats.cpp
ktypesstats.cpp: In member function ‘QString KTypesStats::getFileType(const char*)’:
ktypesstats.cpp:112: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
make[3]: *** [ktypesstats.o] Error 1
```

---

You could try installing an earlier GCC4 release (*gcc-4.1* or *gcc-4.2*), since [this Gentoo bug](http://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=251145) indicates problems compiling with GCC 4.3 (Ubuntu 9.10 provides GCC 4.4 by default).

However, [one of the comments](http://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=251145#c4) indicates that ***kgraphspace*** is a dead project, last updated in 2002.  The commenter recommends [***Filelight***](http://www.methylblue.com/filelight/) as a potential replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Mhh .. it looks a bit like your program depends on Qt 3, not Qt 4.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from akira there'll probably be a deb package providing compatibility with Qt 3, whilst having Qt 4 installed. On Debian these packages are called things like libqt3-headers, libqt3-mt, libqt3mt-dev etc. Try installing some of them, if you're compiling from source you'll probably need the dev versions as well as the plain packages.

[EDIT] KDE 3 and KDE 4 are not compatible with each other as KDE 3 depends on Qt 3 and KDE 4 depends on Qt 4. I don't know whether it's the cause of your problems but you appear to be putting your KDE 4 installation as the prefix, try the KDE 3 one instead.

Comment: All those are the newer version. libqt3-mt-dev is already the newest version, libqt3-mt is already the newest version, libqt3-headers is already the newest version. Many thanks for any more suggestions.

Comment: i use http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to look up package names (eg http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qt3&searchon=names&suite=karmic&section=all) ... @ant2009, have you checked *"./configure --help"* to see if you need to use a specific option to show it where Qt lives?

Comment: and i use just "apt-file search filename" .. with filename something configure.log complains about. furthermore, i think configure uses 'pkg-config' or 'qmake -query' to find out about the qt version, the more interesting part would be to just read the documentation of the software OP wants to compile, there should be stated if it neeeds qt3 or qt4.

Comment: If it refers to Qt >= 3.0.2 then it is almost certainly not going to work with Qt4, as the two libraries are not compatible.

Comment: Hello, I have managed to solve the problem of the qt libaries and headers by setting the path. However, I am having a problem now with the kde libraries. I have updated my question, as there is a lot to type.